# How i can continue execute testing, when first step is failed?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I have testcase.
Test case have 10 independent steps.
When first step failed, another step not execute.

How i can do to continue test?

example:

```
with allure.step('Проверка, что после явной отписки освобождаются pullpoint`ы'):
    for i in range(0, kMaxPullPoints + 5):
    ...
with allure.step('Проверка одновременного запроса PullMessages на один адрес подписки'):
    cpps = CreatePullPointSubscription
    ...
with allure.step('Проверка максимального количества подключений клиентов'):
    def start_th():
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's common technique called `deferred asserts`
You need to wrap assert and catch an exception. Or write a `python decorator` or just `function`.
In python you can do it with `try/catch`.

Also, 10 independent steps better to have in different test cases but in the same test suite (if they check the same module for example).
`Simple rule 1 test - 1 check.`

As for a solution for py.test you can use
http://pythontesting.net/pytest-expect/

Comment: And can i geting the failure stack trace of step? as in the ordinary putest failure ?